# Azure function using hybrid connection

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-hybrid-connections

I have an azure function which is supposed to call an on-prem API. The application works fine in my dev environment. But there is a problem when I deployed it to Azure. I have already set up a hybrid connection for my Azure function to connect to the on-prem server. But when I run the code to get a response from on-prem API I get a 204 error. I believe there is a problem with the connection to on-prem from Azure. Could you review my setting and advice if anything is wrong?
My Code:
var request = new RestRequest("**[https://onPremServer.internal.myDomain.com:534**/api/token"](https://onPremServer.internal.myDomain.com:534**/api/token%22), Method.Post);
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: 204 is not an error but a 'good' `No Content` response, could it be that the request body is not well formatted?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is not related to body format as it is a simple string

Answer (score 0):

204 status code its not an Error. its successfully request and response.
200-206 status code its show successfully. and 204 status code show its not content return by the API. Its Api return content. You can change content from API Side.

> The 204 (No Content) status code indicates that the server has
> successfully fulfilled the request and that there is no additional
> content to send in the response payload body.

[204 status No Content](https://apihandyman.io/empty-lists-http-status-code-200-vs-204-vs-404/#:%7E:text=The%20204%20(No%20Content)%20status,in%20the%20response%20payload%20body.&text=While%20200%20OK%20being%20a,is%20absolutely%20nothing%20to%20return.) by Apihandyman site.

[Azure Functions Using Hybrid Connections](https://www.stefanroth.net/2019/01/13/azure-functions-azure-functions-using-hybrid-connections/) by  stefanroth.